# Bluetooth Not Turning On Dual Boot alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth, windows-10, hp

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 dual boot alongside with windows 10. I am using hp laptop. after the installation the bluetooth was working fine. but after that i opened windows for a while. then again i open ubuntu the bluetooth was not turning on. Kindly guide me I'm new to Ubuntu.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 gives

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci

lsusb gives

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5d5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    dmesg | grep -i blue  gives

[   12.764134] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.764153] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.764157] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.764160] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.764163] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.053209] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=09 hci_rev=d28b lmp_ver=09 lmp_subver=090b
[   13.053213] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 090b, hci rev d28b, hci ver 0009
[   13.053215] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
[   27.156250] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   27.156253] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   27.156258] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Disable Fast Start feature in Windows.

Comment: it didnt work. @Pilot6

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net A3; lsusb` terminal command. And also `dmesg | grep -i blue`. And sis you turn off the computer and on after you disabled Fast Start?

Comment: hey @Pilot6 i have uploaded the image, if you find any mistake in command kindly pardon me. and i am your brother dear... (:--

Comment: I don't need any image. I need text from a terminal.

Comment: I made a typo. The correct command is `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @Pilot6 updated the question with the required commands and output

Comment: Try to completely turn off the laptop and turn off it again. The problem is that Windowas has loaded the firmware.

Comment: hey @Pilot6 community was suggesting to move this comments into chat but i have not that much of reputation. i would like to thank you my bluetooth has started after complete off and on. but now its noit getting paired with my earphone. still i'm trying to resolve it if needed any help will ping you on this comment.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I  have faced a similar issue with 20.04 LTS on Lenovo Thinkpad hardware in the past and resolved using `Blueman`.

Steps to follow-

- Make sure Bluetooth is not hardware/ physically blocked
- Install `Blueman` from repo or, from Git (https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman)
- Run it

It should resolve this issue.

Comment: This is very unlikely.

Comment: Yet, it worked for me as well as for my friend, I would suggest trying once.

Comment: It is completely unclear what OS you were using and what was the BT hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Use this repo https://github.com/rtlwifi-linux/rtw88_8723de

clone it and don the below operation:

- The 8723DE firmware resided in reference/fw/rtw8723d_fw must copy & rename
  to /lib/firmware/rtw88/rtw8723d_fw.bin
- press 'make' to build driver, and then copy rtw88.ko and rtwpci.ko to
  /lib/modules/5.x.y/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/.
- do 'depmod -a'